# Specify to use std::rotate not from boost

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl

I'm having a problem to specify to use the rotate from stl, not from boost. How can I do it?

My entire source can be seen below, which is a simple code of insertion sort method

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::rotate
#include <vector>

// Function to sort the array
struct _ItemCompare {...} ItemCompare;

template<class T>
class Sorters {
public:
    void insertionSort(std::vector<T> &vec, unsigned int size) {
        for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.begin() + size; it++) {
            auto const insertion_point = std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), it, *it, ItemCompare);
            std::rotate(insertion_point, it, it + 1);
        }
    }

};
```

the error track trace can be seen is the code below:

```
In file included from src/balanced_intercalation_multipath.cpp:10:0,
                 from src/balanced_intercalation_multipath.h:29,
                 from main.cpp:7:
src/sorters.h: In member function ‘void Sorters<T>::insertionSort(std::vector<T>&, unsigned int)’:
src/sorters.h:29:19: error: ‘it’ does not name a type
         for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.begin() + size; it++) {
                   ^
src/sorters.h:29:37: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’
         for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.begin() + size; it++) {
                                     ^
src/sorters.h:29:37: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
In file included from src/balanced_intercalation_multipath.h:29:0,
                 from main.cpp:7:

In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:335:18: note: synthesized method ‘Item& Item::operator=(const Item&)’ first required here 
        *__result = *__first;
                  ^
src/sorters.h: In member function ‘void Sorters<T>::insertionSort(std::vector<T>&, unsigned int)’:
src/sorters.h:29:19: error: ‘it’ does not name a type
         for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.begin() + size; it++) {
                   ^
src/sorters.h:29:37: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’
         for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.begin() + size; it++) {
                                     ^
src/sorters.h:29:37: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
```

EDIT1: Put my entire code and also the error
I compile with

> -lboost_serialization -std=c++11

Comment: Docs: (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate). Please post a **complete example** that readers can try.

Comment: You're probably including the wrong header file. P.S. include the *entire* error message.

Comment: That's only **part of** the error message; there is another part that uses the word "error", and that tells you **what** the compiler is complaining about. This part tells you **where** it was looking when it found the error.

Comment: Sorry @PeteBecker, I couldn't understand the error, and now I put the error

Comment: You have a different question now (even though you're still trying to solve the same problem).  Looks like your compiler is not treating the keyword `auto` as C++11.  Either your compiler is too old, or you didn't send the `-std=c++11` switch to the compiler: maybe you spelled it wrong (the number of dashes matters) or maybe you gave it to the linker but not the compiler.  Or maybe added it to CFLAGS but then the compiler command line doesn't use them.

Comment: Any which way, you could comment out that whole function body and just write `auto it = vec.begin();` and you would already see the same error.  `std::rotate` isn't part of the problem you are having.  Boost isn't part of the problem you are having.

Comment: @BenVoigt, When I compile the code withouth the std::rotate it goes well, I have this error when I use the rotate. I keep the includes and the rest of the code.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting `std::rotate`, but you forgot to `#include <algorithm>`.  However, the Boost headers you are using have included it for you.

The error message you are getting is unrelated to Boost, however.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I update the error message and I included the algorithm